# What's the simplest way to run a cron job on a standalone Ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, cron, rubygems

I have a gem that packages one .rb file containing my class and associated methods as well as a corresponding .bin file.

Locally, I can run everything just fine like so:

```
command_to_bin input_file output_file
```

I don't want to run this manually every day so I'm considering using cron on a server, but I'm a little unsure how to proceed.

Do I throw everything into a directory (.gem file, input file, output file) and just point the above cron command at the directory?

I've looked at [this](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28dv%29%3aRun_Ruby_on_Rails_cron_tasks) and sort of understand what's going on. I guess what confuses me the most is that when I look at all the web hosting providers, they mention domains and applications, but I just want to know how to have the standalone script run by itself without it being built into a web application or associated with a domain.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever). It's a wonderful gem to abstract all the nastiness of cron. Just include the command as you have written above and it should be fine.

Comment: Hmm...I'm having trouble getting this to work. I've created a new schedule.rb file and required the whenever gem as well as my command `every 1.day, :at => '12am' do command "command_to_bin -f input_file -o #{Time.now}_output_file" end` and then tried locally running the file by running `ruby schedule.rb` but I get an error saying "every" is undefined. How do I include whenever for my script?

Comment: Have you done `gem install whenever` and run the `wheneverize .` in your project directory?

Comment: I'm just including `require whenever` in my script file.

Comment: You need to `gem install whenever` before you can start using it

Comment: Can you run `wheneverize .` ?

Comment: OK so the whenever gem explicitly looks for the `congfig/schedule.rb` file hierarchy wherever you call it. Locally, everything seems to work, but alluding to my actual question, I'm not sure how to run a server-side script without having to deploy an entire Rails app onto a domain.

Comment: Well, if its the gem that you need, you'll just have to install the gem on your server. I don't think you'll need to install Rails.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install Rails. After you `wheneverize .` the directory and set the schedule in your schedule.rb file, you need to run `whenever --update-crontab` to set everything to the system. Otherwise your cron jobs never get converted to Unix Cron